# How to update the tableListView if the UITabbar item is clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.dict = [self getUpdatedDict:oldDict];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //the cell is rendered from the data of self.dict
}
```

I have a UITabbar with a UITable view inside. So I want to update the uitablelist items every time the user clicks on the tabbar item. Isn't viewDidAppear supposed to be called every time it when the user click the tabbar to enter the view? Anyone know if there is a iOS7 lifecycle chart out there?

Comment: reload tableView in viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, viewDidAppear will be called every time you go back to that controller. I think your problem is that you're not calling reloadData on your table view after you update your array.

Answer (score 1):

Reload the tableView,. Code is here,

```
[Tableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the following line on click method :

```
[yourTableView_name reloadData];
```